# How do I perform Upsert using Enterprise WSDL v54?

Tags: sandbox, c#, wsdl, upsert, enterprise

Attempting to use the Upsert function contained in the Enterprise WSDL (Salesforce Sandbox) version 54. Unfortunately not very familiar with SF development or Upserts, the documentation on the [Salesforce Developer Site](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_upsert.htm) does not seem to match that of what intellisense in VS 2019 (.Net Core 3.1) is asking for.  Here is what v54 upsert() is looking for:

[image]

Here is the current code I am using.  If someone can help me figure out a) how to do an upsert and/or b) what values I need to send for all the other arguments.

```
    public static void updateQuota(DataTable quotaData)
    {
        // Array to hold the updates
        FSS_SFService.Quota__c[] updates = new FSS_SFService.Quota__c[200];

        // Establish a connection to Salesforce
        SalesforceSession session = SalesforceConnection.Login(myUsername, myPassword, myPassword);

        // Use the salesforce connection (SoapClient) to update the quota object
        using (session.salesforceClient)            // ToDo: Check if session was established correctly
        {
            // For each row in the dataTable, update the Quota Object in Salesforce using Upsert
            int updateCount = 1;
            foreach (DataRow row in quotaData.Rows)
            {
                FSS_SFService.Quota__c quota = new FSS_SFService.Quota__c();
                quota.Quota_Ext_ID__c = row["Quota_Ext_ID"].ToString();

                var dateString = row["QuotaDate"].ToString();
                quota.Date__c = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "yyyy-MM-dd", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                quota.Date__cSpecified = true;

                quota.Revenue_Pri__c = (double)row["Revenue"];
                quota.Revenue_Pri__cSpecified = true;

                quota.Quota_Pri__c = (double)row["Quota"];
                quota.Quota_Pri__cSpecified = true;

                quota.Bookings__c = 0;
                quota.Bookings__cSpecified = true;

                quota.OwnerId = row["OwnerId"].ToString();

                updates[updateCount] = new FSS_SFService.Quota__c();
                updates[updateCount] = quota;

                // Perform Upsert when array reaches 200 objects
                if (updateCount >= updates.Length)
                {
                    FSS_SFService.upsertResponse response = new FSS_SFService.upsertResponse();

                    response = session.salesforceClient.upsert("Quota_Ext_ID__c", updates);

                    updateCount = 1;   // Reset the update counter
                }
                else updateCount += 1;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Doesn't look like this thread is getting much attention.  Couple this with not being very familiar with Salesforce and how to integrate, I'm wondering how many people do these sort of integrations.  I know Salesforce is a power CRM tool, but I don't think your want to build your ERP (SAP) system into SF.  So maybe I ask another question, if people are not using the SOAP API, what other tools are people using to interface proprietary system to SF?  Do I move to a REST API?  Thoughts.